# How to auto click a button on site load?

Tags: javascript

i have the below code
this code adds a button that makes an iframe go fullscreen when clicked
i need to add a javascript code to automatically click this button when site loads and the iframe becomes fullscreen when site loads
what code should i add and where should i add it ?
Thanks
.

```
<center><button id="full" style="color:blue;margin: 15px;;font-size:300%;" onclick="goFullscreen('cowboy'); return false">Fullscreen</button></center>
```

```
<script>
function goFullscreen(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    
}
</script>
```

.
i found some codes searching about this
but i dont actually know where to put them in my code

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not allow websites to trigger fullscreen mode on load. There **must** be a user interaction. You can’t fake one by simulating clicking on a button with JS; the browser knows the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can create something called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). These are functions which get immediately invoked by default. You can just update your code like this to achieve this:

```
(function()
    {
    ...
    Your code
    ...
    }
)()
```

I.e., by just wrapping your function inside () and calling it immediately by adding () in the end.

Here is the complete HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center><button id="full" style="color:blue;margin: 15px;;font-size:300%;">Fullscreen</button></center>
  <script>
    (function() {
      // alert is to test if it is working, you can erase this line
      alert("hi")
      var element = document.getElementById("full");
      if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }

    })()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you test this successfully on a website?

Comment: yes it works with other clicks - but like Quentin said it didnt make the iframe go fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

The [`Element.requestFullscreen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) method is among APIs which are categorized as [features gated by user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation). Here's a relevant snippet:

> To ensure applications are unable to abuse APIs that can create a bad user experience when the behavior is not desired, some APIs can only be used when the user is in an "active interaction" state, meaning the user is currently interacting with the web page, or has interacted with the page at least once. Browsers limit access to sensitive APIs like popups, fullscreen, or vibration APIs to active user interactions to prevent malicious scripts from abusing these features.

See the link above for details about how this security mechanism works.

You can use the [`document.fullscreenEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled) property for determining whether or not the fullscreen API is available. Here's an example from the documentation:

```js
function requestFullscreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
    videoElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else {
    console.log("Your browser cannot use fullscreen right now");
  }
}
```